# In Keras, how to use Reshape layer with None dimension?

Tags: python, keras, reshape, keras-layer

In my model, a layer has a shape of `[None, None, 40, 64]`. I want to reshape this into `[None, None, 40*64]`. However, if I simply do the following:

```
reshaped_layer = Reshape((None, None, 40*64))(my_layer)
```

It throws an error complaining that `None values not supported`.

(Just to be clear, this is not `tf.keras`, this is just Keras).

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the argument you pass to `Reshape` layer is the desired shape of one sample in the batch and not the whole batch of samples. So since each of the samples in the batch is a 3D tensor, the argument must also consider only that 3D tensor (i.e. excluding the batch axis).

Second, you can use `-1` as the shape of only one axis. It tells to the `Reshape` layer to automatically infer the shape of that axis based on the shape of other axes you provide. So considering these two points, it would be:

```
reshaped_out = Reshape((-1, 40*64))(layer_out)
```

Comment: This gives - IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @ARPITPRASHANTBAHETY Considering the error, it's very likely that it relates to somewhere else. Are you sure it's caused by the line containing the `Reshape` layer? Anyways, you can ask a new question and provide your code as well as the full error message so that other users can see it and help you.